# creating a jquery custom lightbox setup.

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I'm creating a custom jquery lightbox.

The problem i'm having is the setup function doesn't work as I wanted to, what I wanted to do is when an image is click I want the setup() function to run and update the variables (prev_img, next_img, count, current_img_src). Also when #next and #prev is click I want to run the setup function and update.

```
    <ul id="items">
        <li class="shrink"><img src="foo1.jpg" alt="foo1"/></li>
        <li class="shrink"><img src="foo2.jpg" alt="foo2"/></li>
        <li class="shrink"><img src="foo3.jpg" alt="foo3"/></li>
        <li class="shrink"><img src="bar1.jpg" alt="bar1"/></li>
        <li class="shrink"><img src="bar2.jpg" alt="bar2"/></li>
        <li class="shrink"><img src="bar3.jpg" alt="bar3"/></li>
    </ul>
    <nav>
        <span id="next">Next</span><br/><span id="prev">Prev</span>    
    </nav>
```

script

```
$(function(){
    var prev_img, next_img, count, current_img_src = '';

    $('.shrink img').on('click', function(e){       
        if(e.target.tagName == 'IMG'){
            current_img_src = $(this).attr("src");
            setup();
        }
    });
    $('#next').click(function(){
        console.log(next_img);
        setup();
    });
    $('#prev').click(function(){
        console.log(prev_img);
        setup();
    });

    function setup(){
       count = $('.shrink img').length;    
       $(".shrink img").each(function(){        
            if($(this).attr("src").toString() === current_img_src.toString()){
                prev_img = $(this).prev();
                next_img = $(this).next();
            }
        });
    }
});
```